# Get generated key value while inserting in partitioned table

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-jdbc

Hi I have a table in Postgres, say email_messages. It is partitioned so whatever the inserts i do it using my java application will not effect the master table, as the data is actually getting inserted in the child tables. Here is the problem, I want to get an auto generated column value (say email_message_id which is of big serial type). Postgres is returning it as null since there is no insert being done on master table. For oracle I used GeneratedKeyHolder to get that value. But I'm unable to do the same for partitioned table in postgres. Please help me out.

Here is the code snippet we used for oracle

```
public void createAndFetchPKImpl(final Entity pEntity,
  final String pStatementId, final String pPKColumnName) {


final SqlParameterSource parameterSource =
  new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(pEntity);

  final String[] columnNames = new String[]{"email_message_id"};
  final KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
  final int numberOfRowsEffected = mNamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(
      getStatement(pStatementId), parameterSource, keyHolder, columnNames);
  pEntity.setId(ConversionUtil.getLongValue(keyHolder.getKey()));

}
```

Comment: "GeneratedKeyHolder" implies you're probably using Spring, but we shouldn't have to guess. Details please. JDBC driver version, any higher level abstractions like JPA/Spring, your mapping code, etc.

Comment: Yes we are using spring-jdbc version 3.1.1 . Postgres version being 8.1

Comment: I am getting numberOfRowsEffected as zero and keyHolder.getKey() as null even though the insert is happening in the table.

Comment: OK, first thing: You need to upgrade PostgreSQL *yesterday*, 8.1 is unsupported and outdated. It may not be patched for the significant security issue that's going to be fixed on April 4: http://blog.hagander.net/archives/212-About-security-updates-and-repository-lockdown.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use trigger-based partitioning in PostgreSQL it is *normal* for the JDBC driver to report that zero rows were affected/inserted. This is because the original SQL `UPDATE`, `INSERT` or `DELETE` didn't actually take effect, no rows were changed on the main table. Instead operations were performed on one or more sub-tables.

Basically, partitioning in PostgreSQL is a bit of a hack and this is one of the more visible limitations of it.

The workarounds are:

- `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` directly against the sub-table(s), rather than the top-level table;
- Ignore the result rowcount; or
- <strike>Use `RULE`s and `INSERT ... RETURNING` instead (but they have their own problems)</strike> (Won't work for partitions)

Comment: I tried inserting using "RETURNING currval('email_messages_email_message_id_seq')" but still I'm unable to get that value. However I'm able to achieve it by using a stored procedure for insert. Can you please specify how actually I can get the value using returning clause

Comment: @user1495565 Are you using rule-based or trigger-based partitioning?

Comment: If I do change my partitioning using rules instead of triggers(current code), as per the postgres current implementation, it allows only unconditional INSTEAD rules to contain RETURNING; furthermore there can be at most one RETURNING clause among all the rules for the same event. SO I cannot return values from all the rules as I have multiple partitions for the same table.

Comment: @mohansammeta Ah, good point, I forgot about that. So you basically have to work around it in the app layer per the 1st two points.

Comment: What does the trigger do? If it inserts the same record into the master table, it could retrieve its master id, which in turn could be passed on via Java method invocation.

Comment: @DrH Trigger is to insert records in child tables(partitions) and it will not insert in master table.

Comment: @CraigRinger I should not insert/update directly against subtables as they are logically partitions and my application logic is unaware of their presence. It will deal with parent table only.

Comment: @mohansammeta Well, that leaves you with the last option then: ignore the result rowcount. If you need to get the generated IDs you're pretty much stuffed. As I said, partitioning in PostgreSQL is in some ways a bit of a hack, particularly when it comes to result rowcounts and returning from DML.

Comment: @CraigRinger So then I'm thinking to fetch the nextval(seq) and use it while inserting.Are there any drawbacks for this approach other than one extra DB call?

Comment: @mohansammeta No other drawbacks, and you can even grab chunks of IDs at a time with (eg) `SELECT nexval('my_id_seq') FROM generate_series(1,50);` . Or you can alter the sequence to increment in chunks of (say) 50 and have a local ID allocator that hands IDs out and only gets them from the DB when a new chunk is needed. This is how Hibernate does it and it works pretty well.